# Return Multi Row DataSet as Single Row CSV without Temp Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm doing some reporting against a silly database and I have to do

```
SELECT [DESC] as 'Description' 
FROM dbo.tbl_custom_code_10 a
INNER JOIN dbo.Respondent b ON CHARINDEX(',' + a.code + ',', ',' + b.CC10) > 0 
WHERE recordid = 116
```

Which Returns Multiple Rows

```
 Palm
 Compaq
 Blackberry
```

Edit * 
Schema is

```
Respondent Table (At a Glance) ...

*recordid   lname   fname   address CC10     CC11     CC12     CC13*
116         Smith   John    Street  1,4,5,   1,3,4,   1,2,3,   NULL

Tbl_Custom_Code10

*code   desc*
0       None
1       Palm
10      Samsung
11      Treo
12      HTC
13      Nokia
14      LG
15      HP
16      Dash
```

Result set will always be 1 row, so John Smith: | 646-465-4566 | Has a Blackberry, Palm, Compaq | Likes: Walks on the beach, Rainbows, Saxophone

However I need to be able to use this within another query ... like

```
Select b.Name, c.Number, d.MulitLineCrap FROM Tables
```

How can I go about this, Thanks in advance ...

BTW I could also do it in LINQ if any body had any ideas ...

Comment: Just curious why you are artificially limiting your solution by saying "without Temp Table"? If the solution works and it is fast enough, why do you care if it uses a temp table or not?

Comment: @Aaron Thank you for the Reply ... MSSQL 2008 ... My T-SQL is a little rusty (damn you LINQ !) can I do it inline with my select statement and use a temp table ?  That would be great

Comment: We need more information. How are "Tables" b and c related to the output of tbl_custom_code_10 and dbo.Respondent? Why is the first query using recordid = 116? Is this something that depends on the output of the second query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to make a comma-separated list based on a query (just replace the query inside the first WITH block). Now, how that joins up with your query against b and c, I have no idea. You'll need to supply a more complete question - including specifics on how many rows come back from the second query and whether "MultilineCrap" is the same for each of those rows or if it depends on data in b/c.

```
;WITH x([DESC]) AS 
(
  SELECT d FROM (VALUES('Palm'),('Compaq'),('Blackberry')) AS x(d)
)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + [DESC]
  FROM x 
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'varchar(max)'),1,1,'');
```

**EDIT**

Given the new requirements, perhaps this is the best way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMultiLineCrap
(
    @s VARCHAR(MAX)
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @x VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    
    SELECT @x += ',' + [desc]
        FROM dbo.tbl_custom_code_10
        WHERE ',' + @s LIKE '%,' + RTRIM(code) + ',%';
    
    RETURN (SELECT STUFF(@x, 1, 1, ''));
END
GO

SELECT r.LName, r.FName, MultilineCrap = dbo.GetMultiLineCrap(r.CC10)
    FROM dbo.Respondent AS r
    WHERE recordid = 116;
```

Please use aliases that make a little bit of sense, instead of [just serially applying `a`, `b`, `,c`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3), etc. Your queries will be easier to read, I promise.

Comment: I Added above, the result set is always a sinlge row and it will be a status report for the respondent so John Smith: | 646-465-4566 | Has a Blackberry, Palm, Compaq | Likes: Walks on the beach, Rainbows, Saxophone etc ...

Comment: Thank you for you patients in the face of my obvious inability to state this question correctly ... Also One quick question can you pass the table in as a pararmeter in MSSQL ??? ... I have Custom Tables 1- 100 ...

Comment: No, you can't name the table dynamically inside the function, that would require dynamic SQL which is not supported inside the function. If all the custom tables have the same basic columns, I'd implement a single table with 1-100 as an INT column / key to define which "table" you're talking about.

Comment: No, you don't want to maintain 100 `CASE...WHEN` blocks either. If you implement a single table instead of 100 tables, you just need an additional where clause, e.g. `FROM dbo.tbl_custom_codes WHERE codeset = 10 AND ...`.

Comment: Ah, Unfortunately I do not have the source for the application so I can not change the schema of the database ...